# tasksel: apt-get failed (100)

Tags: 16.04, php, lamp, tasksel

I'm trying to install tasksel and Setting up my PHP/MySql Development Environment in my laptop, I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and I get this error when I try this command line:

```
Laptop:~$ sudo tasksel install lamp-serve
tasksel: apt-get failed (100)
```

I googled about the problem and found some solutions but no one worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had Same Problem.
Type `sudo taskel` In prompt and then install it from the interface.

Space To Select Tab to select ok and enter to exit

Comment: Thank you, I solved the problem by installing all the needed package manually, but now I tried your suggestion it's working for other packages.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try

`sudo tasksel install lamp-server`

if `tasksel` is not installed then do

`sudo apt install tasksel`

Comment: tasksel is already installed,